# How to reduce iterations for each pixel?

Tags: for-loop, unity-game-engine

I am building a game in Unity and I have a RawImage with the dimensions 1024 x 1024 and it doesn't have a texture initially. I build one at runtime. At the moment, I have a button that when pressed generates a new texture and sets it to the RawImage. Basically, I generate a random array of Vector2 that contains 4 random positions within the dimensions of the RawImage.
I'm facing long processing times because I need to set each pixel of the RawImage to my desired background color and all of this for just 4 positions. In other words, I do 1024 x 1024 = 1048576 iterations when I would just need 4. Here is a graphical representation as an example:
[image]

*In this example I used a resolution of 40x40 in order to make the points more visible.

Here is the code that I use at the moment:

```
    public RawImage myImage;

    public void GenerateButtonPressed()
    {
        Texture2D topTexture = new Texture2D(40, 40);
        Vector2[] randomValues = new Vector2[4];
        Color pointColor = Color.black;
        Color backgroundColor = Color.cyan;

        for(int i=0; i < randomValues.Length; i++)
        {
            randomValues[i] = new Vector2(Random.Range(0, 40), Random.Range(0, 40));
        }

        int randomCounter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < topTexture.width; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < topTexture.width; j++)
            {
                if(i == randomValues[randomCounter].x && j == randomValues[randomCounter].y)
                {
                    topTexture.SetPixel(i, j, pointColor);
                    randomCounter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    topTexture.SetPixel(i, j, backgroundColor);
                }
                
            }
        }
        topTexture.Apply();
        myImage.texture = topTexture;
    }
```

As you can see, I do 2 nested for loops with a pretty big index size just to set 4 points. Is there a way to reset the background without doing all those iterations and to set just the 4 points when the button is presed?
Any amount of help would be appreciated because this improvement for sure will make my game more enjoyable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I can see there is no other way than setting each pixel either by using the `SetPixel` method or the `SetPixels` method where you have to give an array with all colors. One way though would be to use the default static values for the colors there are some texturecoloring predefined. It doesnt change perfomance though cause it does nothing else than you do with Set Pixel.

Comment: One thing that I would recommend for efficiency, however, is to first set all background colors and then color the points. If queries are quite expensive and if you can avoid them in a loop, that's a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment already what you are doing isnt wrong but it is not that cost efficient.

I would try something like this:

```
public RawImage myImage;

public void GenerateButtonPressed() {
    Texture2D topTexture = new Texture2D(40, 40);
    Vector2[] randomValues = new Vector2[4];
    Color pointColor = Color.black;
    Color backgroundColor = Color.cyan;

    for(int i = 0; i < topTexture.width; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < topTexture.width; j++) {
            topTexture.SetPixel(i, j, backgroundColor);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < randomValues.Length; i++) {
        randomValues[i] = new Vector2(Random.Range(0, 40), Random.Range(0, 40));
        topTexture.SetPixel(randomValues[i].x, randomValues[i].y, pointColor);
    }
    topTexture.Apply();
    myImage.texture = topTexture;
}
```

With this code you just set all pixels and then set the pixels with the Random locations. Obv some pixels get set twice with this but its better because you dont need the if anymore.